# Which script in MRTK enhances hologram stabilization?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I couldn't figure out what part of the Mixed Reality Toolkit takes care of stabilization of holograms. Could any point me to that?

I realized that stability of holograms is enormously improved when MRTK is imported. Without MRTK, the stability of a simple cube I would say it is pretty bad, jittering a lot with head and body movement.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer @derHugo ! I couldn't find a script called WorldAnchorManager. Under wich package is it? Thanks!

Comment: It seems you have a different version of the toolkit... I have the MRTK v2.0RC1, and I don't see this script. Maybe it is no longer there? See my [project hierarchy](https://imgur.com/a/Quu27ec). Thanks!

Comment: lol then maybe state that in your question ... the MRTK 2.0 is clearly marked as `2.0` .. everything else refers to the currently released MRTK 2017.4.3 .. the 2.0 is still in pre-release ...

Comment: anyway it was more a guess actually .. the MRTK 2 works completely different though

Answer (score 1):

WorldAnchorManager is not yet ported to MRTK v2. You can still find the script in the HTK and copy over to use it.

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/4509

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple script. The MRTK Team has an interesting documentation about the hologram stabilization topic and what factors are important: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/hologram-stabilization.html

In simple words there is a Focus Point that has to be aligned with your holograms. You can analyse the position of the "Stabilization Plane" with the hololens device portal.  My assumption is that you activate the Depth buffer through the MRTK, but not without MRTK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hologram-stability

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Unity 2018 and experiencing hologram jitter, even with a simple scene (i.e. just a plain cube) please check out this thread-
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2018-3-and-hololens-holograms-are-not-stable.647734/

There is an issue where some users in 2018 have severe jitter in their Holograms, when in 2017 they were rock solid. If you could take the time to check it out and vote on the issue it would help potentially get this issue resolved.
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/hololens-holograms-are-jittering-since-unity-2018